# Help with Cron on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron

I'm a newbie with Magento 2 so please bear with me.

I've been trying to make the cron run. First, I tried to [Create a Password File](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/secy/secy-cron.html#config-cron-secure-apache-pwd). I was able to create the directory, but whenever I ran the command to create the password it says:

> htpasswd command not found

As a workaround, I manually created the password file with the help of [this site](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/).

Question A: Why can't it find htpasswd command?

Question B: Is it the same if I used the manual method?

Question C: What should be the file name/extension? **.htpasswd** or just **password**?

--

Second, I modified the **.htaccess** file inside **pub** folder with the code below so I can run the **pub/cron.php** file on browser but it's not working.

```
<Files cron.php>
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Cron Authentication"
 AuthUserFile /home/floweraddict123/public_html/fa-private/password/.htpasswd
 Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Question D: What's wrong with my .htaccess code?

Since it wasn't working, I removed the .htaccess restriction first, then run that file again on browser (twice as suggested on Magento user guide) and I got a blank page both times. I looked in my database and there was a **cron_schedule** table with the values of today's date, so I guess it worked. I already put back the restriction, but I think the cron is still not properly setup. I guess if I get the answers above then I can try this part again.

Question E: Is it just supposed to be blank?

--

Lastly, I tried to check my existing crontab with this code:

```
crontab -u <Magento file system owner name> -l
```

Question F: Is the file system owner (a user with root privileges) name same as my cPanel username?

We're hosted on GoDaddy, if that helps.

Apologies for the loads of questions, but looking forward to the replies.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A: Most likely you didn't have `apache2-utils` installed on your remote server. You can install it by this command:

`sudo apt-get install apache2-utils`

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/378965/htpasswd-executable-is-missing

B: Same, no differences

C: Up to you, but I usually use **.htpasswd** as it can be hidden on normal `ls` command.

D: Please make sure `.htpasswd` is inside the folder specified on `AuthUserFile`

E: If you see sth, it means errors happens. If you see blank page, it means the cron.php runs properly. Of course, you've to grant the necessary rights.

F: Unlikely. You can check the user list by this command:

`cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1`

Ref: http://www.tech-faq.com/how-to-list-unix-users.html

P.S: I usually run **cron.php** via `crontab`, this method is new for me ;-)